# Compute if giant component exists

Tags: python, optimization, networkx, graph-theory

I have a set of integers, which create a graph by connecting integers of the set for which be binary representation only differs by one position, e.g:

```
set={0, 3, 16} --> their binary representation are  {00000, 00011, 10000}
```

This would be a graph in which two nodes are connected (0 and 16) and 3 is not connected. Now I want to compute, if the set creates a graph, that is fully connected. In other terms, if the giant component of the graph contains all nodes. At this moment, I only have solved this problem using networkx, by first creating a graph in networkx and then using `nx.is_connected(G)`

```
G = nx.Graph()
for key in set:
    G.add_node(key)

for n1 in G.nodes(data=True):
    for n2 in G.nodes(data=True):
        if bin(n1[0]^n2[0]).count("1") == 1:  #compare if binary rep. differs at one position
            G.add_edge(n1[0], n2[0], weight=1)

if nx.is_connected(G):
```

This is problematic as it is slow and I would prefer **not** to use networkx. Can you help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done in base python using a dictionary to construct the graph and then breadth-first search to determine if the graph is fully connected. Here is an implementation without networkx.

```
def giantComponentExists(nums):
    # Construct a graph as a dictionary
    graph = {n:[] for n in nums}

    # Add edges between nodes
    for n1 in nums:
        for n2 in nums:
            if bin(n1^n2).count("1") == 1:  #compare if binary rep. differs at one position
                graph[n1].append(n2)

    # BFS search to determine if graph is fully connected
    fringe = [nums.pop()]
    visited = set()
    while fringe:
        for edge in graph[fringe[0]]:
            if edge not in visited:
                fringe += [edge]
        visited.add(fringe[0])
        fringe.pop(0)
    return len(visited) == len(graph.keys())

example1 = {0,1,16}
example2 = {0,3,16}
print(giantComponentExists(example1))
print(giantComponentExists(example2))
```

Comment: Your way to compute the Hamming distance actually comes out 10x slower in my timing experiments...

Comment: This seems to work. I need some time to have a closer look. Thanks!

Comment: @PaulBrodersen interestingly you're right the way I suggested to speed up the hamming distance calculation was slower for most number pairs when I tested it. That's not what I intuitively expected.

Comment: Just a follow-up question: For performance reason I'm trying to implement your version into a numba decorated function. Currently I'm failing because of the dictionary. Do you know how to get your function working in numba?

Comment: @HighwayJohn No sorry I'm not familiar with that decorator/library. A quick poke around makes it look like Dicts may [not yet be fully supported](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.43.0/reference/pysupported.html#dict)?

Answer (score 1):

If you are concerned about speed, then C++ is the way to go.

To determine if a graph is completely connected it is sufficient to determine that the number of maximal cliques is exactly one.

Here is the pseudo code for finding the maximal cliques

```
LOOP
    CONSTRUCT empty current set
    SELECT V arbitrary vertex
    add V to current set
    remove V from graph
    LOOP      // while set is growing
        added_to_set = false
        LOOP V over vertices in graph
            LOOP Vset over current set
                IF Vset connected to V
                     add V to current set
                     remove V from graph
                     added_to_set = true
                     break;
        IF added_to_set == false
           break;    // the set is maximal
    ADD current set to list of sets
    IF graph has no remaining vertices
       OUTPUT sets found
       STOP
```

For a C++ implementation of this see code at https://github.com/JamesBremner/PathFinder2/blob/dbd6ff06edabd6a6d35d5eb10ed7972dc2d779a6/src/cPathFinder.cpp#L483

This code can handle graphs of several thousand nodes in less than a second.  What performance do you get with networkx?

Comment: I can handle about 10 graphs of size 1000 per second. Thanks for sharing this pseudo code. I'll have a look

Comment: @HighwayJohn  That is very decent performance.  I do not believe you will be able to find anything significantly faster than that,  Some more details about the performance I am getting https://github.com/JamesBremner/PathFinder2/wiki/Performance

Answer (score 1):

Your `Graph` instantiation is a bit inefficient. `Graph` is basically a dictionary of dictionaries. Adding edges one-by-one can result in copying of subdictionaries if the graph is large enough. This issue goes away if the `Graph` object is instantiated with all edges pre-computed. With a few small changes, the vast majority of the execution time is then spent in the "edge detection", i.e. here:

```
bin(n1[0]^n2[0]).count("1") == 1
```

#### Code

Assume a script `binary_graph.py` with the following two versions of your code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import networkx as nx
from itertools import combinations

@profile
def v1(nodes):
    G = nx.Graph()
    for key in nodes:
        G.add_node(key)
    for n1 in G.nodes(data=True):
        for n2 in G.nodes(data=True):
            if bin(n1[0]^n2[0]).count("1") == 1:  #compare if binary rep. differs at one position
                G.add_edge(n1[0], n2[0], weight=1)
    return nx.is_connected(G)

@profile
def v2(nodes):
    edges = [(n1, n2) for (n1, n2) in combinations(nodes, 2) if bin(n1 ^ n2).count("1") == 1]
    G = nx.Graph(edges)
    return nx.is_connected(G)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    nodes = range(1000)
    print(v1(nodes))
    print(v2(nodes))
```

#### Profiling

Profile the script by running:

```
kernprof -l binary_graph.py
python -m line_profiler binary_graph.py.lprof
```

This yields the following profiling information:

```
Timer unit: 1e-06 s

Total time: 0.888128 s
File: binary_graph.py
Function: v1 at line 5

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
     5                                           @profile
     6                                           def v1(nodes):
     7         1          9.0      9.0      0.0      G = nx.Graph()
     8      1001        326.0      0.3      0.0      for key in nodes:
     9      1000       1457.0      1.5      0.2          G.add_node(key)
    10      1001        348.0      0.3      0.0      for n1 in G.nodes(data=True):
    11   1001000     312677.0      0.3     35.2          for n2 in G.nodes(data=True):
    12   1000000     548470.0      0.5     61.8              if bin(n1[0]^n2[0]).count("1") == 1:  #compare if binary rep. differs at one position
    13      9864      22631.0      2.3      2.5                  G.add_edge(n1[0], n2[0], weight=1)
    14         1       2210.0   2210.0      0.2      return nx.is_connected(G)

Total time: 0.175228 s
File: binary_graph.py
Function: v2 at line 16

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
    16                                           @profile
    17                                           def v2(nodes):
    18         1     160153.0 160153.0     91.4      edges = [(n1, n2) for (n1, n2) in combinations(nodes, 2) if bin(n1 ^ n2).count("1") == 1]
    19         1      12890.0  12890.0      7.4      G = nx.Graph(edges)
    20         1       2185.0   2185.0      1.2      return nx.is_connected(G)
```

In other words, with a more optimised networkx `Graph` instantiation, it becomes clear that the vast majority of your execution time is networkx independent.